# How does "PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);" handles List of WebElements?

Tags: java, selenium

I just want to know the working of PageFactory.initElements(driver, this) how it populates searchSuggestions webElement and also if I'm not using thread.sleep(500) , it is throwing stale element reference exception with thread.sleep it's working fine.

```
public SearchObjects(WebDriver driver) 
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
@FindBy(id="navbar-query")
WebElement searchBar;

@FindBy(xpath="//div[@class='navbar-suggestionsearch__search-result']")
List<WebElement> searchSuggestions;

public SearchObjects(WebDriver driver) 
{
    this.driver = driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
}
public void searchOnImdb(WebDriver driver, String str) throws InterruptedException
{
    searchBar.sendKeys(str);
    Thread.sleep(500);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PageFactory.initElements()` only creates proxies for variables marked with annotations `@FindBy`. This method does not actually search for these elements. For a `WebElement`, a proxy for `WebElement` is created similarly for `List<WebElement>`.

Refer to https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/PageFactory.java method `initElements()` which calls the method `proxyFields()`. In this method the `decorate()` method of `Decorator` is called - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/DefaultFieldDecorator.java. In the decorate() method you will find the respective proxies being created with the respective `InnvocationHandler`. The `InnvocationHandler` handles the actual searching of elements etc.

Now when something like `driver.findElements()` is used, it first goes to the proxy which calls the actual method. - https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/internal/LocatingElementListHandler.java and https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/support/pagefactory/internal/LocatingElementHandler.java.

Try and using an explicit wait with `ExpectedConditions` - https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html.